# Taxonomy Relationships

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I've created two taxonomies:

- Make
- Model

This is for a CPT Vehicles. It goes without saying, Make would be your make (Honda / Toyota / Ford / etc) and then one would select the Model based on the Make.

How do I setup the relationship between Make and Model? Or have I gone about this all wrong and it should in fact be a single taxonomy 'Make & Model'?

Im not looking for:

```
Vehicle CPT
 |-> Make
 |-> Model
```

Im looking for:

```
Vehicle CPT
 |-> Make
      |--> Model
```

Comment: Do you want to assign both taxonomies to the same post type?

Comment: Yes, so I want to have a 'vehicle' which is a CPT. I want to set that to a (make) 'Honda' and a (model) 'Civic'.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer for you. You should set the `$post_type` argument to your CPT's name for both taxonomies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taxonomies are not child of each other unlike terms, which can be. Take a look at this flowchart:

[image: Taxonomy relationship]

Model is a child of Make, and should not be registered as a new taxonomy. What you are trying to do, is something like setting Ford as a child of Honda, which is not right. Instead, register 1 single Make taxonomy, and then create sub-taxonomies, just like what we do in categories.

Take a look at [`register_taxonomy()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) function at the codex, and register your taxonomy as hierarchical, then create sub taxonomies as model.

Comment: thanks, but assigning both to the vehicle CPT wouldnt make the one taxonomy dependent on the other. eg: Honda > Civic, Toyota > Corolla, Ford > Focus, etc.

Comment: sorry, please see revised original post for further clarification. from my understanding, your solution means two separate / unrelated taxonomies attached to a CPT without any relationship to eachother.

Comment: Different taxonomies can't be child of each other. Then you have 2 options. Either define only 1 hierarchical taxonomy, and set the model as its child, or you can use terms, which also supports the same. Just like categories and sub-categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use term meta to set a Model is a Make`s child, let us assume a Make "Honda" has term_id 3,

```
// when add terms to taxonomy Model
add_term_meta($term_id, 'make_id', '3');
```

So when add a connection to taxonomy "Make" and ""Model. when can add metabox to taxonomy term creation page.

Even so, We also need change the taxonomy select ui as chained, it is a little complex.