# How Do I Register Two Taxonomies with one Parent of the Other?

Tags: taxonomy

Trying to figure out the best way to do this. Hope I can get some help. So I am developing a plugin which handles a custom post type of cars. I am looking to add. A couple of category taxonomies related to the CPT ie Model and Make.  I have been able to successfully add the model taxonomy like so:

```
   //model taxonomy options
        $model_labels = array(
          'name' => _x( 'Models', 'taxonomy general name' ),
          'singular_name' => _x( 'Model', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
          'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Models' ),
          'all_items' => __( 'All Models' ),
          'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Model' ),
          'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Model:' ),
          'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Model' ), 
          'update_item' => __( 'Update Model' ),
          'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Model' ),
          'new_item_name' => __( 'New Model Name' ),
          'menu_name' => __( 'Models' ),
          'back_to_items' => __( '? Back to models' ),
        );    

      // Now register the taxonomy

        register_taxonomy('models','car', array(
          'hierarchical' => true,
          'labels' => $model_labels,
          'show_ui' => true,
          'show_admin_column' => true,
          'query_var' => true,
          'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'model' ),
        ));
```

Now the question is how do I go about registering a separate "make" taxonomy as the parent of the "model" taxonomy? Is that possible with WordPress? Ie having a "category > subcategory > post" setup? Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A taxonomy cannot be a parent/child of another taxonomy.  The "hierarchical" notation indicates that you can have a hierarchy within that taxonomy. [This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/277179/taxonomy-relationships#277180) addressed car Make & Model graphically.

Think "category" - "subcategory" relationship.

You can, however, have multiple levels of terms within a given taxonomy.  If you look at the [wp_insert_term() codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term), you will find a "parent" parameter that sounds like what you want to use.

So, within taxonomy "make-model" you might have Term=Ford, terms with $parent=="Ford" => (Astro,Mustang,F150), $parent=="Honda" => (Civic, Accord, Fit), etc.

[This article by WP Mayor](https://wpmayor.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-wordpress-taxonomies/) goes over custom taxonomies, and hierarchical taxonomies, in great detail.

Comment: Thanks Mike! This has been very helpful. There more I think about it, the more I see no real reason to use multiple taxonomies.